# How to read the ipaddress value in @IntegrationTest

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest-assured

I have to execute my tests on a different machine and have the ipaddress and port for that machine.How to read the ipaddress?

Currently doing this :

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = service.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest("server.port:8084")
```

Reading in the file :

```
    @Value("${local.server.port}")
    int port;
    private String uri = "/service/addName";
```

Now how to add the ip address and read it in the files?

Comment: The port you're configuring here is for the embedded tomcat (that's why it's called `local.server.port`), by definition, that's the same ip address as the rest of your application. If you're saying that you're having two separate instances of your app (for some reason) and want to connect from one to the other, you can just create a new property and manually add the port and IP address of the remote app there.

Comment: can you give an example? should I remove the local.server.port property or substitute that with the new ipaddress and port?